# Use regular expressions to determine type of variable in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

I'm new to python and am wondering if there are more efficient ways to complete this homework problem:

Write a function mytype(v) that performs the same action as type(), and can recognize integers, floats, strings, and lists. Do this by first using str(v), and then reading the string. Assume that lists can only contain numbers (not strings, other lists, etc...), and assume that strings can be anything that is not an integer, float or list.

The problem requires using Regular Expressions.
Here's what I have so far, and it works to my knowledge.
I'm wondering if there exists ways to do this WITHOUT so many if statements? ie more concise or more efficient?

```
import re 

def mytype(v):
   s = str(v)
   # Check if list
   list_regex = re.compile(r'[\[\]]')
   l = re.findall(list_regex, s)
   if l:
      return "<type 'list'>"
   # Check if float
   float_regex = re.compile(r'[0-9]+\.')
   f = re.findall(float_regex, s)
   if f: 
      return "<type 'float'>"
   # Check if int
   int_regex = re.compile(r'[0-9]+')
   i = re.findall(int_regex, s)
   if i:
      return "<type 'int'>"
   # Check if string
   str_regex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+')
   t = re.findall(str_regex, s)
   if t:
      return "<type 'string'>"


x = 5
y = 5.5
z= .99
string = "hsjjsRHJSK"
li = [1.1,2,3.2,4,5]


print mytype(x) # <type 'int'>
print mytype(y) # <type 'float'>
print mytype(z) # <type 'float'>
print mytype(string) # <type 'string'>
print mytype(li) # <type 'list'>
```

Comment: Hey! According to the limitation you presented in your description I'm not sure whether you should consider efficiency, either way, to make your code shorter you can use a `for` statement to iterate through the different reg expressions and try to match them on your string.

Comment: You should brush your regexps (for example your list matches on "[bla" or "][" which is probably not what you want. You can avoid ifs by pairing the regexps with result in tuples and iterate over them.

Comment: As mentioned, your regexps are way too grabby. Besides the brackets, also `"5.5.5"` would be detected as float and "`xyz23"` as int. Make sure you mark your boundaries / starts and ends for what the regexp matches correctly.

Comment: BTW, your question might be better suited for StackExchange :: Code Review. (just an idea)

Answer (score 3):

Use `group` to match and get a captured group name and pipe `|` in regex.

**Regex**: [`(?P<list>\[\[^\]\]+\])|(?P<float>\d*\.\d+)|(?P<int>\d+)|(?P<string>\[a-zA-Z\]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/V0aIHM/1)

**Details:**

- `|` or
- `(?P<>)` python named capturing group

**Python code:**

```
def mytype(v):
    s = str(v)
    regex = re.compile(r'(?P<list>\[[^]]+\])|(?P<float>\d*\.\d+)|(?P<int>\d+)|(?P<string>[a-zA-Z]+)')
    return  r"<type '%s'>" % regex.search(s).lastgroup
```

Input:

```
print(mytype(5))
print(mytype(5.5))
print(mytype(.99))
print(mytype("hsjjsRHJSK"))
print(mytype([1.1,2,3.2,4,5]))
```

Output:

```
<type 'int'>
<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>
<type 'string'>
<type 'list'>
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/gj7QGb)

Comment: This is awesome, I learnt something new. However, it should come with a warning that it captures the first type, i.e., 'mt5' will return 'string' and '5mt' will return 'int'

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there exists ways to do this WITHOUT so many if
>   statements? ie more concise or more efficient?

Without affecting your results, and more strictly following the rules, we can toss one `if` statement and half your code:

```
def mytype(v):
    s = str(v)

    # Check if list
    if re.search(r'[\[\]]', s):
        return "<type 'list'>"

    # Check if float
    if re.search(r'[\d]+\.', s): 
        return "<type 'float'>"

    # Check if int
    if re.search(r'[\d]+', s):
        return "<type 'int'>"

    # Assume strings are anything that's not an int, float or list
    return "<type 'string'>"
```

This is even before considering your regular expressions.  You don't need to call `re.compile()` for this usage. Your `list` test could easily catch a `dict` but `dict` wasn't in your requirements.  The `z = .99` only works because by the time it turns to string, it's `"0.99"`.  An actual string of `".99"` would have failed your `float` test.  There's an order dependency to your `float` and `int` tests -- that should be commented.